# Why there is nothing appear when using Vis JS in Modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I am totally new in Vis JS and try to use the plugin. I have follow the steps [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/basic_usage/peer.html) by replicate the JS and HTML but nothing is appear in Modal. I already import the CSS and JS as well. However, at plain page it is OK just problem to display on Modal.

Red color below should be the diagram will appear.

[image]

```js
// create an array with nodes
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
    { id: 1, label: "Node 1" },
    { id: 2, label: "Node 2" },
    { id: 3, label: "Node 3" },
    { id: 4, label: "Node 4" },
    { id: 5, label: "Node 5" }
]);
// create an array with edges
var edges = new vis.DataSet([
    { from: 1, to: 3 },
    { from: 1, to: 2 },
    { from: 2, to: 4 },
    { from: 2, to: 5 },
    { from: 3, to: 3 }
]);
// create a network
var container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");

// provide the data in the vis format
var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
};
var options = {};

// initialize your network!
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vis-data@latest/peer/umd/vis-data.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vis-network@latest/peer/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/vis-network/styles/vis-network.min.css" />

<div id="mynetwork"></div>
```

Comment: The code works in the fiddle, so I would assume the problem lies with the implementation of the modal. Which library are you using for that?

Comment: Hi, after troubleshooting just now I found the solution by putting height and width `<div id="mynetwork" style="height:400px;width:100%;"></div>`. However, found new problem here whereby the topology is not really middle of the division. need to drag manually. how to solve for this problem? or I need to post a new issue?